# How many Watts?

Tags: power-supply

I live off -grid and have 12 volt solar system with a 500 watt inverter.
I need to find out how many watts my speaker /amplifier/docking station uses. Im usually good at figuring out watts..but this one stumps me. It says : 20V.
Input 100-240V 2A
Output DC 20V 3A

Im not sure which numbers I use to multiply to get my watts

Can anyone tell me how many watts it uses?

Comment: This sounds like a small transformer substitute power supply (switcher). (Input 100-240Vac @ 2A) (Output 20V @ 3A). Your 500 watt inverter should not be loaded by this.

Comment: http://shop.p3international.com/p/kill-a-watt

Answer (score 5):

The output is 20 volts and 3 amps. This tells you that the output power is a maximum of 60 watts. Without knowing exactly what kind of electronics produces this, it's hard to be more precise. If it's a switching supply/amp, then you might reasonably expect 85% efficiency. Then the total power required would be 60/0.85, or 71 watts, but without knowing the efficiency, it's hard to get more accurate than that.

Comment: As already stated the maximum output power is 60W and when delivering 60W the AC input is ~70W.  however the typical power will probably be much less and will depend upon the design and also how loudly the system is played.  I would expect the average power for modest volumes to be more like 10-20W.

Comment: @KevinWhite The average power for modest volumes will be more like *one* Watt.

Comment: @EJP - could be. I agree the average output power will be very low but the  total power from the supply would probably very much more. I was being conservative because the OP didn't give much information.  I have measured docking stations that take 5 watts or so when doing nothing.